# Does using only one instance of a class template still cause code bloat?

Tags: c++, templates, inline

Suppose I have a template class in which I make hundreds, even thousands of deep copies of one instance. As I understand it, the compiler will inline this class wherever it will be used - this can cause code bloat. But does the below example do this? If my program only ever uses one 'version' of the class template (in the example below I have used 3) would code bloat still occur.

```
#include <array>

template <int N>
class Example {
public:
    std::array<int, N> parameter;

    Example(std::array<int, N> value){
        parameter = value;
    };

    ~Example(){};
};

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 3> simple = {1, 2, 3};
    Example<3> * primitive = new Example<3>(simple);

    for(int i=0; i<100; ++i){
        new Example<3>(*primitive);
    }

    // Leak everything
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your understanding is mistaken – it will not inline more than with any other class. You will get the same code as if the array size were hard-coded.

Comment: Is this just due to compiler optimization or because I only used a single 'version' of the template. @molbdnilo

Comment: If you only use a single instance of a template, then obviously the compiler is only going to instantiate that template once. So there is no code bloat. You seems concerned that the compiler is going to add a whole lots of code to your program because you create multiple objects, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @IvorDenham-Dyson Instantiating a template is the same as writing that code by hand, except only things you actually use get created. The "bloat" people are worried about comes from multiple instantiations of functions that do essentially the same thing and could be merged into one, not from inlining. (And the fear of bloat is also pretty much a 1990's thing, when a few kilobytes here and there mattered.)

Comment: "If my program only ever uses one 'version' of the class template (in the example below I have used 3)" You have only used one version, the template where N is 3 unless you mean one version where N=3. not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, compiler will inline the code of constructor at each of 2 points of usage here.
But it is not a bloating. You will have the same situation using a non-template class with the hard-coded N. If you want to save a code space, you may use a compiler-supported language extension to disable inlining of the constructor.